# Question about PDE, diffusion equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

> Let $u$ be sufficiently smooth and satisfy
>   $$
> \begin{cases}
> u_t − u_{xx}= f(x,t)       & \{(x,t) : 0 < x < 1, 0 < t < 1\},\\
> u(0,t) \ge 0, u(1,t) \ge 0 & 0 \le t \le 1\\
> u(x, 0) \ge 0              & 0 \le x \le 1
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> 1. Prove that $u \ge 0$ on $\{(x,t) : 0 < x < 1, 0 < t < 1\}$ if $f(x,t) \ge \epsilon$ in  $\{(x,t) : 0 < x < 1, 0 < t < 1\},$ where $\epsilon > 0$.
> 2. Prove that $u \ge 0$ on $\{(x,t) : 0 < x < 1, 0 < t < 1\}$ if $f(x,t) \ge 0$ in $\{(x,t) : 0 < x < 1, 0 < t < 1\}$.

**My approach**

For the equation given as the condition, I think that this is related to diffusion equation, but I need to assume 2 solution ( for example, a&b) and come up with its difference w, so I can rewrite the condition as the proper diffusion equation with boundary conditions. After this process, I thought this would be related to maximum principle, but I'm quite stuck since it's all about .
I want to know whether my approach is right, or is there another proper approach for this problem. 
And, for these 2 questions, I get the point that the difference is that f(x,t) can be 0 in question #2, but I don't get its significance. 
Would be thankful if you could come up with proper approach for each questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your region is $D = \{ (x,t): 0<x<1, 0<t<1\}$ and its boundary is $\partial D$, then $D \cup \partial D$ is compact, hence the image under $u$ of this set is also compact, i.e. closed and bounded by Heine-Borel since we're dealing with a real-valued function. Thus, the function must attain its minimum somewhere in $D \cup \partial D$.

It suffices to show that this minimum cannot be attained on the line $t=1$ or in the interior. For the latter case, if it were in the interior, then we'd have $u_t = u_x = 0$ at this point, as well as $u_{xx} \geq 0$. This contradicts the heat equation since $f$ is strictly positive. If the minimum instead lies on $t=1$, then again $u_x=0$, $u_{xx} \geq 0$, but now $u_t \leq 0$ -  otherwise this minimum would be  attained vertically below  this line. Again, a contradiction.  So the minimum is attained on $x=0,$ $x=1,$ or $t=0$, thus the function is non-negative everywhere.

For the second part, define a new solution of the heat equation by:
\begin{equation}
v(x,t) = u(x,t) - \frac{\epsilon}{2}x^2.
\end{equation}
In this case, $v_t-v_{xx} = f(x,t)+\epsilon >0$, so the previous part applies to $v$, i.e. $v$ attains its minimum on $\partial D$ less $\{t=1\}$. So if the minimum value of $u$ on $\partial D$ less $\{t=1\}$ is $M$, then:
\begin{equation}
u  \geq v \geq M - \frac{\epsilon}{2},
\end{equation}
since the maximum value of $|x|$ is $1$.
We may then take $\epsilon \to 0^+$ and conclude that the minimum value of $u$ is attained on $\partial D$ less $\{t=1\}$.